# Obtaining price and names of eBay goods

Tags: ios, iphone, web-services

I'm new in iOS development and I want to search eBay items with my app. I found the reference on the [eBay development network](https://www.x.com/developers/ebay), but I can't find out how to search eBay items by keywords.

For example, I enter `mobile`, and I want to get the list with eBay mobile items with their prices. I've already tried `ASIHTTPRequest` to get information from one webservice, but:

1. I can't find proper webservice in
   [https://www.x.com/developers/ebay][1]
2. May be you can give me an example, how to load proper ebay items.

Update: thanks to your help, I saw get request of eBay web service

```
http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?
   callname=FindProducts&
   responseencoding=XML&
   appid=YourAppIDHere&
   siteid=0&
   version=525&
   QueryKeywords=harry%20potter&
   AvailableItemsOnly=true&
   MaxEntries=2
```

But I would like to use a POST request. And eBay gives XML body of that request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FindProductsRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <QueryKeywords>Harry Potter</QueryKeywords>
  <MaxEntries>2</MaxEntries>
  <AvailableItemsOnly>true</AvailableItemsOnly>
</FindProductsRequest>
```

But to form post request I, of course, need request URL. What URL should I use? Is it `open.api.ebay.com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Ebay Shopping API](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/FindProducts.html). for that you need to register and login to get APIKey.

Visit the Link : http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/FindProducts.html

For [Making an API Call](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/Concepts/ShoppingAPI_FormatOverview.html) and You can obtain data in the JSON, XML, NV (Name-Value Pair), and SOAP formats using the Shopping API. The HTTP GET and HTTP POST methods are supported
visit the Link : http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/Concepts/ShoppingAPI_FormatOverview.html

If you are using a URL (and the HTTP GET method)

```
http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?

   callname=FindPopularItems

   &appid=YourAppIDHere

   &version=517

   &siteid=0

   &responseencoding=NV
```

If you are using the `HTTP POST` method, use the `X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-ENCODING` value (or a requestencoding URL parameter) to specify that your input is in one of the following formats: `NV (Name-Value Pair), JSON, XML, or SOAP`.

The output (response data) will be in the same format as the input, so there is no need to specify a X-EBAY-API-RESPONSE-ENCODING value. However, you can specify an output format that is different from your input format by using a `X-EBAY-API-RESPONSE-ENCODING` value.

This example shows standard Shopping API headers for an `HTTP POST` call
(which uses the same http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping? endpoint as a `GET` call).

The `X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-ENCODING` header specifies NV for Name-Value Pair input, and can be changed as follows::
`XML for XML input, SOAP for SOAP input, and JSON for JSON` input.

```
 X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: FindPopularItems

   X-EBAY-API-APP-ID: YourAppIDHere

   X-EBAY-API-VERSION: 517

   X-EBAY-API-SITE-ID: 0

   X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-ENCODING: NV
```

Source: http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/Concepts/ShoppingAPI_FormatOverview.html#URLExamples

Comment: actually, for me it's difficault to form url string with this description. can you give an example of url to find the products (like in my update). I understood request body, but I still don't understand request url

Comment: Use HTTP GET method instead of POST your call is Correct.

Comment: Yes, get method is correct, and url is ok for get method. But what url should be for post method? (because I should only use post methods for the app)

Comment: Check The Postmethod Example : http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/Concepts/ShoppingAPI_FormatOverview.html#URLExamples

Comment: I faced another issue, I used the request, but I responce I don't get the prices of the products. Can I change it to correct the situation?

Comment: Check Here A sample http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findCompletedItems.html#Samples  which Schows Currentprice .

Comment: Also you can check here http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/FindProducts.html#Response.ItemArray.Item.BuyItNowPrice  

Also i think you have to call another api with the corresponding product id then you can get price.